# Bitfields in C without variable name

Tags: c, bit-fields

What is the use of unnamed bit-fields in C?

Example :

```
typedef struct fun {
unsigned int                 :8;
unsigned int foo1            :1;
unsigned int foo2            :1;
unsigned int foo3            :1;
unsigned int foo4            :1;
unsigned int foo5            :1;
}dig;
```

What is the use of line :

```
   unsigned int                 :8;
```

Comment: To reserve eight bits at the beginning for future extensions? You really have to ask the author why he or she put it there, all we can do is speculate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called unnamed bit field. C11 standard states about it and possible usage:

> 6.7.2.1  Structure and union speciﬁers
>
> A bit-ﬁeld  declaration  with  no  declarator, but  only  a  colon 
>   and  a  width,  indicates  an unnamed bit-ﬁeld.  106) As a special
>   case, a bit-ﬁeld structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no
>   further bit-ﬁeld is to be packed into the unit in which the previous
>   bitfeld, if any, was placed.
>
> 106) An  unnamed  bit-ﬁeld  structure  member  is  useful  for 
>   padding  to  conform  to  externally  imposed layouts.

Comment: So if there is 8 named bitfield variable(foo[0-7]:1) that means they are allocating 8 (unnamed)+ 8(8 named bit-field ) bit memory?

Comment: Yes. Basically extra bits allocated (or reserved) at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

An unnaed bitfield like this can be used for a number of reasons. One reason as already mentioned is in order to pad out the other values in order to match an external layout where there are values that are unused. I have seen it used this way to map directly onto hardware.

They could also be left unnamed for future expansion

Although you can give a name to indicate it is unused it is possible for someone to set those bits using the field you have provided and by not naming it you make the user jump through hoops in order to set the bits. You also end up with `unnamed1`, `unnamed2` etc scattering your bitfields

For example on a microprocessor I have used there are bits that are specifically for the debugger to use and by not naming them it makes them harder for a developer to set them unintentionally.

The problem was on a previous version they were named and a colleague used them. Update of the compiler and headers and no longer building code